# How to remove a file beginning with a dash (in Unix like mode)

Tags: linux, unix, escaping, git-bash, rm

I have accidentally created a file in GitBash (a Unix like environment) with the name `- -l` (I have absolutely no idea how I managed to do this in the first place :)

```
Johnny (master #) scipy-tentative-numpy-tutorials $ ls -l
total 1
-rw-r--r--    1 Johnny   Administ      956 May  7 16:24 - -l
-rw-r--r--    1 Johnny   Administ      562 May  7 16:21 README.md
```

I wish to delete (remove) that `- -l` file.

I have tried a few ways but no luck. e.g.

```
rm "- -l"
rm "-\ \-l"
rm -\ \-l
```

These didn't work.

Please how do I delete the `- -l` file?

Thank you!

Comment: FYI -- StackOverflow doesn't support GitHub's markdown extensions; triple-backticks for code blocks are one of those. Use four-space indents, or the `{}` editor button which creates them, instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a double hyphen (`--`) to stop flag parsing:

```
rm -- -\ -l
```

Alternatively, you can even use tab completion:

```
rm -- \- # Then press TAB immediately after typing the final -
```

This assumes that's the only file with a leading hyphen in the directory. Bash is smart enough to automatically escape the space in the middle of the file name.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's wrong or not, but the backslashes before the dashes are not required.

Comment: Extra backslashes are harmless.

Comment: Harmless, but I *do* tends to agree that they reduce the readability of this answer (by *implying* a behavior that isn't actually necessary is part of the answer). Consider [edit]ing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
rm ./-\ -l
```

or this:

```
rm -- -\ -l
```

The first solution tells the program that you're looking for a file in the current directory, thus implying the argument is not an option.

The second solution uses `--` to tell the program that subsequent arguments starting with `-` are not options.